# How to parse argv in prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

When I'm trying to pass a list to Prolog program, I get a string in argv. I need to recover list somehow from this string or find a way to pass list.
Thanks.

Edit: I've tried opt_arguments, but I got this error:

> "ERROR: validate_opts_spec/1: Type error: `flag_value' expected, found`
>   term' (an atom) (unknown type 'term' in option 'transactions')".

Comment: Not clear what you mean.... How do you invoke the program? From the command line? You always get a list of atoms in argv, how come it is a string? You need a list of what? and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux:

```
$ swipl [a,b,c]
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.5.1-31-gd53ee81)
...
```

and then

```
?- current_prolog_flag(argv, Argv),Argv=[L|_],atom_to_term(L,T,[]).
Argv = ['[a,b,c]'],
L = '[a,b,c]',
T = [a, b, c].
```

After @Boris comment, here is a better way, in sense it covers both cases

```
$ swipl [a, b, c]
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.5.1-31-gd53ee81)
...
?- current_prolog_flag(argv, Argv),atomic_list_concat(Argv,Atom),atom_to_term(Atom,Term,[]).
Argv = ['[a,', 'b,', 'c]'],
Atom = '[a,b,c]',
Term = [a, b, c].
```

Comment: if you have `$ swipl [a, b, c]` this is already broken. But the problem is the question, not your answer...